# How to record val_loss and loss per batch in keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I'm using the callback function in keras to record the `loss` and `val_loss` per epoch, But I would like to a do the same but per batch. I found a callback function called `on_batch_begin(self,batch,log={})`, but I not sure how to use it.

Comment: Show what you are doing now per epoch please so that we can see what you expect per batch.

Comment: history = model.fit_generator(...) then history.history['loss'] and history.history['val_loss'] gives us the loss and val_loss per epoch

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is an example of custom callback. Following and modifying an example from [here](https://keras.io/callbacks/):

```
class LossHistory(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
        self.losses = []
        self.val_losses = []

    def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
        self.losses.append(logs.get('loss'))
        self.val_losses.append(logs.get('val_loss'))

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(10, input_dim=784, init='uniform'))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop')

history = LossHistory()
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=128, nb_epoch=20, verbose=0, validation_split=0.1,
          callbacks=[history])

print history.losses
# outputs
'''
[0.66047596406559383, 0.3547245744908703, ..., 0.25953155204159617, 0.25901699725311789]
'''
print history.val_losses
```

Comment: Logs dictionary doesn't seem to have a 'val_loss' key. Hence the final print statement always shows an empty list

Comment: If you don't set validation data you don't have loss values in a history object?

Comment: I did set validation data though

Comment: Try to print out `history.history.keys()` in order to check your stats.

Answer (score 4):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import keras

class LossHistory(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
        self.history = {'loss':[],'val_loss':[]}

    def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
        self.history['loss'].append(logs.get('loss'))

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        self.history['val_loss'].append(logs.get('val_loss'))

history = LossHistory()

model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu', input_dim=100))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='binary_crossentropy')

# Generate dummy data
import numpy as np
data = np.random.random((1000, 100))
labels = np.random.randint(2, size=(1000, 1))

# Train the model, iterating on the data in batches of 32 samples
model.fit(data, labels, epochs=10, batch_size=32, 
          validation_split=0.2, callbacks=[history])

# Plot the history
y1=history.history['loss']
y2=history.history['val_loss']
x1 = np.arange( len(y1))
k=len(y1)/len(y2)
x2 = np.arange(k,len(y1)+1,k)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line1, = ax.plot(x1, y1, label='loss')
line2, = ax.plot(x2, y2, label='val_loss')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

From tf.keras documentation it seems that on_batch_end doesn't include val_loss

on_batch_end: logs include `loss`, and optionally `acc`
    (if accuracy monitoring is enabled).

as mentioned here:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/Callback

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer. I was able to calculate it. I calculated manuel LossFunction(Binary Cross Entropy). Because, if i use "model.evaluated(x_test, y_test)" then the training phase takes quite a long time.

But at the end of each batch, when keras calculates and performs with BCE, the process is much faster

```
 class LossHistory(keras.callbacks.Callback):
        
        def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
            self.losses = []
            self.val_losses= []
    
        def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
            y_pred = self.model.predict(x_test_scaled)
            bce = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=False)
            val_loss = bce(y_test, y_pred).numpy()
            self.val_losses.append(val_loss)
            self.losses.append(logs.get('loss'))
```

It remains only to fit the model.

```
hist = LossHistory()

model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),
              loss=keras.losses.binary_crossentropy,
              metrics=[keras.metrics.binary_crossentropy])

history = model.fit(x_train_scaled, y_train,batch_size=256, epochs=15,
          verbose=1,callbacks=[hist], validation_data=(x_test_scaled, y_test))
```

And end of the model fit, you can show validation loss for every batch step.

```
hist.val_losses
```