# Keras validation loss and accuracy metrics per batch produces a list of 'None'

Tags: tensorflow, validation, keras, callback

I am currently trying to get the loss and accuracy of each batch for both the training and validation of my Keras Model. I have managed to successfully do so for the loss and accuracy training but am running into problems when trying to obtain the equivalent for the validation loss and accuracy.

I was basing my work of this [query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42392441/how-to-record-val-loss-and-loss-per-batch-in-keras) and have adapted the code slightly for my application. The **issue** is that I just receive a list of 'None' values.

I created my own LossHistory class shown below. I want to be able to get the metrics for each batch and then the each epoch.

```
class LossHistory(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
        self.history = {'loss':[],'val_loss':[], 'accuracy':[],'val_accuracy':[], 'loss_avg':[],'val_loss_avg':[], 'accuracy_avg':[],'val_accuracy_avg':[]}

    def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
        self.history['loss'].append(logs.get('loss'))
        self.history['val_loss'].append(logs.get('val_loss'))
        self.history['accuracy'].append(logs.get('accuracy'))
        self.history['val_accuracy'].append(logs.get('val_accuracy'))

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        self.history['loss_avg'].append(logs.get('loss'))
        self.history['val_loss_avg'].append(logs.get('val_loss'))
        self.history['accuracy_avg'].append(logs.get('accuracy'))
        self.history['val_accuracy_avg'].append(logs.get('val_accuracy'))
```

I can still get the average values of the validation loss and accuracy. In other words, the validation metrics after each epoch. I am just not able to get those metrics for each batch.

Would anyone know why this is the case? I tried looking at the Keras documentation about [customer callbacks](https://keras.io/guides/writing_your_own_callbacks/) but couldn't make find anything much regarding the validation metrics.

Not sure if I'm missing anything obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validation loss and metrics are evaluated at the end of each epoch, there is no per-batch validation loss and metrics as computed by Keras.

Answer (score 0):

The API does not support, but still you can do it. Below is a Pseudo Code. If Time permits I shall try out and put a cleaner version.

```
def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
     if batch%10 == 0: # Better dont evaluate for all Batch
        x_val = self.validation_data[0]
        y_val_true = self.validation_data[1]
        y_val_pred = self.model.predict(x_val)
        loss = self.compiled_loss(y_val_true, y_val_pred,regularization_losses=self.losses)
        self.history[str(batch)+'_Loss'].append(loss)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom call back like

```
class MultipleValidationCallBack(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    
    def on_batch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        for thisValidationType in validationSets:
            #datagen = 
            thisLoss = self.model.evaluate(validationSets[thisValidationType])
            logs[thisValidationType+"_loss"] = thisLoss[0]
            logs[thisValidationType+"_acc"] = thisLoss[1]
```

You can refer [Medium_Story](https://github.com/Gelesh/Multiple_Validation_Set/blob/main/Multiple_Validation_Call_Back.ipynb) for detailed explanation and [workable code with example on github](https://github.com/Gelesh/Multiple_Validation_Set/blob/main/Multiple_Validation_Call_Back.ipynb)